# How to check a distinct value exists (true/false) from the given multiple records in T-sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table withe different columns as shown below

```
 Ref Number Service Numbers Service type code   OpenDate    CurrentAppointDt    PreviousAppointDt   Time_Stamp  Lettert_created
78892   485992  78892TA 02/16/12    04/17/12    03/21/12    2/17/12 9:00 AM FALSE
78892   485992  78892TA 02/16/12    04/17/12    03/21/12    3/19/12 9:29 AM FALSE
78892   485992  78892TA 02/16/12    04/17/12    03/21/12    3/19/12 9:30 AM TRUE
78892   485992  78892TA 02/16/12    04/17/12    03/21/12    3/8/12 11:32 AM FALSE
78892   485992  78892TA 02/16/12    04/17/12    03/21/12    3/20/12 9:59 AM FALSE
94329   140055  94329   03/21/07    04/20/07    04/02/07    2/1/12 9:41 AM  FALSE
94329   140055  94329   03/21/07    04/20/07    04/02/07    3/21/07 10:00 AM    FALSE
94329   140055  94329   03/21/07    04/20/07    04/02/07    3/21/07 10:09 AM    FALSE
94329   140055  94329   03/21/07    04/20/07    04/02/07    3/22/07 11:21 AM    FALSE
94329   140055  94329   03/21/07    04/20/07    04/02/07    3/27/07 9:01 AM FALSE
94329   140055  94329   03/21/07    04/20/07    04/02/07    3/27/07 12:19 PM    FALSE
94329   140055  94329   03/21/07    04/20/07    04/02/07    12/2/11 12:55 PM    FALSE
107126  478952  107126TA    02/06/12    03/28/12    02/28/12    3/16/12 4:52 PM FALSE
107126  478952  107126TA    02/06/12    03/28/12    02/28/12    3/16/12 5:33 PM TRUE
107126  478952  107126TA    02/06/12    03/28/12    02/28/12    3/16/12 11:58 AM    FALSE
107126  478952  107126TA    02/06/12    03/28/12    02/28/12    3/14/12 2:09 PM FALSE
107126  478952  107126TA    02/06/12    03/28/12    02/28/12    2/24/12 2:00 PM FALSE
107126  478952  107126TA    02/06/12    03/28/12    02/28/12    2/24/12 12:15 PM    FALSE
107126  478952  107126TA    02/06/12    03/28/12    02/28/12    2/24/12 12:15 PM    FALSE
```

If I take the distinct values for the above  Ref Number I get as follows

```
78892                       
94329                       
107126
```

The time_stamp is always between CurrentAppointDT and PreviousAppointDt.
For these RefNumbers I need to see if the 'Lettercreated' is False/true.
I need the output as follows:

```
Ref Number  Service Numbers Service type code   OpenDate    CurrentAppointDt    PreviousAppointDt   Lettert_created
78892   485992  78892TA 02/16/12    04/17/12    03/21/12    TRUE
94329   140055  94329   03/21/07    04/20/07    04/02/07    FALSE
107126  478952  107126TA    02/06/12    03/28/12    02/28/12    TRUE
```

Please help me if i can get a T-sql script in 1 select statement.  It is a great help if any one can give me a solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple grouping command suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just looking for the case where the reference number has any record set to "True", otherwise list it as "False".  If this is the case, try this:

```
select Ref_Number, Service_Numbers, Service_type_code, OpenDate, CurrentAppointDt, PreviousAppointDt,
  case max(case when Lettert_created='True' then 1 else 0 end)
    when 1 then 'True'
    else 'False'
  end
from tbl
where time_stamp between CurrentAppointDT and PreviousAppointDt
group by Ref_Number, Service_Numbers, Service_type_code, OpenDate, CurrentAppointDt, PreviousAppointDt
```

Comment: You could just say `max(Letter_created)`, since `'True' > 'False'`

Comment: Thank you Chezy525,  I tried the above query it is very quick and fast.  The result what i am expecting is exactly same.  But I have small question, when i query distinct on the main table for ref_Numbers i am getting 690 records where as from the above script i only get 10 records. Could you please sugget me where it is going wrong.

Comment: @desi, it's hard to say without access to the actual data, but I'd start by slowly removing columns from the `group by` clause (and the `select` or it won't work). And if you get a different number of results, than you have found the column which creates unique sets.  Remember that `select distinct colA from tbl` is the same as `select colA from tbl group by colA`